# How to sort SC results from search REST API

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

I need to sort my list of sites retrieved by search rest call but when trying to perform the action the list is not sorting. if I go to the xml I can see a property Title on which I should apply the sorting.

[image: Xml]

This is my query, I have tried with `sortlist=Title:ascending` also but not working. Any ideas please?

```
http://mysharepoint:27180/sites/portal/_api/search/query?queryText='ClientSiteType%3AClientPortal*%20contentclass%3ASTS_Site'&rowlimit=500&startrow=0&enableSorting=true&orderby=Title:ascending
```

Comment: You seem to be missing quotes, try it as sortlist='Title:ascending'

Comment: Got 500 INTERNAL error when changing with simple quotes
http://mysharepoint:27180/sites/portal/_api/search/query?queryText='ClientSiteType:ClientPortal* contentclass:STS_Site'&rowlimit=100&startrow=0&enableSorting=true&sortlist='Title:ascending' . In fiddler I see <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"><m:code>-1, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.REST.SearchServiceException</m:code><m:message xml:lang="en-US">An unknown error occurred.</m:message></m:error>  Removing sortlist='Title:ascending' I can see the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because the "Title" is not sortable.

You need to set the "Title" managed property to be sortable.

Central Administration -> Manage service applications -> Search service application -> Search schema -> Managed Properties -> find and edit "Title" managed property -> Enable "sort" .

When we change managed properties or add new ones, the changes take effect only after the content has been re-crawled. You must perform a full crawl after making changes in managed properties.

[Manage the search schema in SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/search/manage-the-search-schema)

If you are using SharePoint Online, crawling happens automatically based on the defined crawl schedule. To make sure that the changes are crawled and fully re-indexed, we must request a re-indexing of the site, or only re-index the list or library.

How to [manage search schema in SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema).

Comment: Thanks, you are correct, I checked the managed properties and I realized there is another field mapped to ows_SiteName which is sortable and I can sort based on this field.